# Why Amplify DataStore is not starting?

Tags: ios, react-native, aws-amplify

I faced the problem with using DataStore and GraphQL in my react native app. When I'm trying to write/get any data I see this in the console:

```
LOG  [DEBUG] 56:36.775 DataStore - Starting DataStore
LOG  [DEBUG] 56:36.776 DataStore - Starting Storage
```

And then nothing happens. For example, in this code the second console log will not be executed:

```
console.log('Start');
const users = await DataStore.query(User);
console.log('End');
```

It's a fresh RN app and Amplify packages. I've tried to re-create the project from scratch and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with Hermes, the polyfill from this issue helped to solve the problem: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/8176

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call `DataStore.start()` or `DataStore.observeQuery()` first in your app lifecycle before other methods.

Comment: Hi, I don't see that it is required in this [manual](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/react-native/). But I've tried to add start() and now I'm getting this error: `DataStore - Schema is not initialized. DataStore will not function as expected. `

Comment: Are you importing the model schemas? E.g. `import { User } from './models';`

Comment: Now yes, but I got the same problem... Schema is imported then after "DataStore -Starting Storage" nothing is happening:
`LOG  [INFO] 23:00.773 DataStore - validating schema {"schema": {"enums": {}, "models": {"User": [Object]}, "nonModels": {}, "version": "82a003ac64f504cd2b49d6ed73b8a5bc"}}
 LOG  [INFO] 23:00.774 DataStore - DataStore Init models
 LOG  [INFO] 23:00.775 DataStore - DataStore Models initialized
 LOG  Start
 LOG  [DEBUG] 23:00.779 DataStore - Starting DataStore
 LOG  [DEBUG] 23:00.780 DataStore - Starting Storage
`

Comment: facing the same issue, any resolution?